# Adding an element and it's class name via JS

Tags: javascript

I want to add an image with class name to my div using pure Java Script. How can i do that? Here is my JS code.

```
function show(){
    var y = document.getElementById("gallery1");
    y.innerHTML="<img src='css/images1/img/img4.jpg'/>"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function show(){
    var y = document.getElementById("gallery1");    
        y.innerHTML= y.innerHTML + "<img src='css/images1/img/img4.jpg' class='specifyclassnamehere'/>";
}
```

Hope you're trying to append the image. So you must add it to the inner HTML.

Another option would be:

```
function show(){
    var y = document.getElementById("gallery1"),
        image = document.createElement("img");
        image.src= "css/images1/img/img4.jpg";
        image.setAttribute("class","specifyclassnamehere");
        y.appendChild(image);
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/jasuzo/1/edit)**

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add an image with a `class` attribute, you can either create an image element and append it to your `div` (or parent element):

```
function show(){
    var y = document.getElementById("gallery1");

    var image = new Image();
    image.src = "css/images1/img/img4.jpg";
    image.setAttribute("class","myclass");

    y.appendChild(image);
}
```

Or even include directly into your `img` tag, like this:

```
<img class="myclass" src='css/images1/img/img4.jpg'/>
```

Here is a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tgpmy87g/), see if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```js
  function show(){
        var y = document.getElementById("gallery1"),
            tempDiv = document.createElement("div"),
            image = document.createElement("image");
        console.log(y);
        image.setAttribute('src',"https://www.google.fr/images/srpr/logo11w.png");
        image.setAttribute("class","myclass");
        
        tempDiv.appendChild(image);
        console.log(tempDiv);
        y.innerHTML=tempDiv.innerHTML
    }
```

```html
<div id="gallery1"></div>

<a href="" onClick="show(); return false">Click me</a>
```